# Retrieve value of cell below, based on horizontal search of cell rows above

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently using Google Sheets. I have a spreadsheet that has a horizontal row of dates at the top. I'm attempting to search the horizontal date row for TODAY, and then return the value of a cell vertically below that header. So if TODAY's date is found in "H1" then return the value of "H24", if TODAY's date is found in "Y1" return the value of "Y24" etc and so on.

I've tried `=vlookup` and `=hlookup`, but I can't get and semblance of results that aren't an error.

Any help at all would be appreciated, as I'm definitely an Excel/Sheets novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=FILTER(A24:Z24,A1:Z1=TODAY())`

If the current data is in cell H1 then the formula should output the contents of cell H24